# How can I evaluate a value in a Python generator at the time I create the generator, not at the time I iterate it?

Tags: python, django, generator

The following is my code:

```
import itertools

i = itertools.chain()
for a in [1, 2, 3]:
    i = itertools.chain(i, (a for _ in range(2)))

print(list(i))
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Is there a way I can access the value of `a` when creating the generator, rather than when I iterate it in the `print` statement?

I'd like the output to be `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`, ie, the value of `a` when the generator was created.

This is a trivial problem, but in my case I am iterating 1,000,000 rows in the outer loop, then in the inner loop generating 8 rows for each of those million, so I'm keen to keep it a generator.

Nb. The use case is I'm iterating a table in the outer loop, creating sub-objects for each row, passing the primary key to the sub-objects. The numbers are pretty large, so I want to build up the generator, then bulk insert after the loop (using Django's `Model.objects.bulk_create(generator)`). But by the time I call `bulk_create` the primary key is always set to the last row in the outer loop.

```
gen = itertools.chain()
for id in ParentModel.objects.all().value_list('id', flat=True)):
    gen = itertools.chain(gen, (InnerModel(fk=id) for i in range(10000)))
InnerModel.objects.bulk_create(gen)
```

All the generated InnerModels point to the last OuterModel in the list.

Comment: I don't get why you are using `itertools.chain`... Why don't you use a nested loop in the generator: `ids = ParentModel.objects.all()...; gen = (Innermodel(fk=id) for _ in range(10000) for id in ids)`. Also instead of chaining by pairs you can use `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: Thanks @Bakuriu I'm actually creating several objects in the inner loop, so was hoping to access `id` in several generators at once. However repeating the id loop isn't so bad, but I can't get your syntax working. I'm doing `ids = (i for i in range(3))` `gen = (x for _ in range(5) for x in ids)` and getting `[0, 1, 2]` - what happened to the `range(5)`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry you have to swap the the `for`s: `for id in ids for _ in range(10000)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind wrapping the tuple into a lambda:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> i = itertools.chain()
>>> for a in [1, 2, 3]:
>>>     i = itertools.chain(i, (lambda x: (x for _ in range(2)))(a))
>>> print(list(i))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

The idea is to copy the value of `a` of each iteration. `lambda`'s argument can do that. In each iteration, a local variable `x` is created and assigned with `a`.

Comment: This answer is worse than @user2357112's in terms of efficiency, maintainability, code brevity, or memory consumption, and I'm not going to use it, but I prefer it thank you! Creating that local variable is exactly what I was trying to do! So the right answer to my broader problem is user2357112's, but this does answer the specific (and misguided) question in the title, and the points will make more difference to you than user2357112. Hope that's OK user2357112, both posts very much appreciated.

Comment: PS. I've checked and it does work for the Django example too - `for id in ..all()` `gen = itertools.chain(gen, (lambda x: (InnerModel(fk=x) for _ in range(3)))(id))` `InnerModel.objects.bulk_create(gen)`

Comment: @Chris: Thank you :) I'm not familiar with django, so I skipped the second part of the question. Glad to see that works!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to restructure your code to use a two-`for` genexp, so that `id` has the right value when it's needed:

```
InnerModel.objects.bulk_create(
        InnerModel(fk=id) for id in ParentModel.objects.all().value_list('id', flat=True)
        for i in range(10000))
```

As another benefit, you won't get the nasty stack overflow you're building up to with those nested `chain`s.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks. I'm creating several different sub-objects so was trying to share the ID generator between several `InnerModelOne, Two..` instantiations. But that is a false economy - the ID list will come from the database as a fully instantiated list so I may as well store it and iterate repeatedly. Further, as you mention, your solution avoids those nested chains.